Having issues with image paths in a tailwind and react project
I am trying to use javascript to set a url path to use with a variable but the path for my image is behaving strangely.
The path used for the src attribute produces empty images but the one used inside tailwind and others like it work fine. This problem also applies with using the style attribute, so I doubt its src attribute, style attribute or the path at fault. The src attribute also works with absolute link to images online, but it is just relative links that do not work.

You need to clear your understanding of how to add images in React. Because in react you first need to import the images using the relative path and you shouldn't use the path itself in the src.
import React from 'react'
import luffyImage from "../assets/luffy.jpg"
// the image relative path is ../assets/luffy.jpg

const Home = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      {/* Using the path directly - this won't work */}
      <img width={700} src="../assets/luffy.jpg" />

      {/* Using import - this will work */}
      <img width={700} src={luffyImage} />
    </div>
  )
}

export default Home

If you do the first way, it will show a broken image

I hope, it helps. Cheers 
